# Bulk SMS - Twilio

Tags: javascript, sms, twilio, twilio-api

I'm trying to send SMS with Twilio SMS api. I'm trying to send 2,000 SMS and only 200 are being delivered. I read that I need to send in batches of 100, so I changed my code to break the array into chunks of 100 each one and just have one API call for it but that didn't worked, only the first number in the array got a SMS.

Another way you can do this (from what I read) is that you can do different API calls synchronously, one after another and you shouldn't have problems. I'm right now sending SMS after SMS but I always get "Error: 20429 - Too Many Requests" after 200 are successfully sent.

Here's my code:

```
//After I grab all the numbers: 

var cleanNumbers = []
let recipientAmount = 1;
let numberStart = 0;
let numbersLen = numbers.length

while (numberStart < numbersLen) {
  let maxNumbers = Math.min(numbersLen, numberStart + recipientAmount);

  for (let i = numberStart; i < maxNumbers; i++) {
     let number = numbers[i]['phone_number'].replace(/[^\d]/g, '')
     if (number.length > 10 && number[0] === '1') {
         number = number.substring(1)
         cleanNumbers.push('1' + number)
     }
     else {
         cleanNumbers.push('1' + number)
     }

     if (i == maxNumbers - 1) {
        var params = {
          'body': `${event_sms_message}`,
          'messagingServiceSid': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
          'to': cleanNumbers
        }

     sendMessage(params)

     cleanNumbers = []
     numberStart = numberStart + recipientAmount;
    }
  }
}
```

Function that makes API call

```
async function sendMessage(params) {
  let msg = await client.messages.create(params, function(err, data, message) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("ERROR:");
      console.log(err)
      return 'done'
    }
    else {
      console.log("SUCCESS:");
      console.log(data)
      return 'done'
    }
  })
  .then(message => 
    console.log(message.sid)
  );
}
```

Does anyone know a better route or if I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heyoooo, Twilio Developer Evangelist here.

> one after another and you shouldn't have problems

This is not what your code does. You're calling `sendMessage` in a loop without waiting for it to be done. This most likely will result in X almost parallel requests which lead to the `too many request` response.

A way to solve this is to wrap your code into an async function and `await` it. For that to work you have to tweak `sendMessage` a little bit to return the promise (or use `client.messages.create` directly) that is returned by the Twilio helper library.

```
async function sendMessage(params) {
  return client.messages.create(params)
}
```

With these adjustments, you can wrap your loop into an async function and wait for every request to succeed first.

```
(async () => {
  while (numberStart < numbersLen) {
    try {
      let maxNumbers = Math.min(numbersLen, numberStart + recipientAmount);

      for (let i = numberStart; i < maxNumbers; i++) {
        let number = numbers[i]['phone_number'].replace(/[^\d]/g, '')
        if (number.length > 10 && number[0] === '1') {
          number = number.substring(1)
          cleanNumbers.push('1' + number)
        } else {
          cleanNumbers.push('1' + number)
        }

        if (i == maxNumbers - 1) {
          var params = {
            'body': `${event_sms_message}`,
            'messagingServiceSid': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            'to': cleanNumbers
          }

        await sendMessage(params)

        cleanNumbers = []
        numberStart = numberStart + recipientAmount;
      }
    } catch(e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }
})();
```

This code will then wait for `client.message.create` to succeed and you shouldn't run into rate limiting errors (`too many requests`) anymore.

Let me know if that helps. :)

Comment: Hey, one quick question, how would you handle the error on ```client.messages.create``` ?? I left them after the return on ```sendMessage()``` and if there's an error, it stays on a loop of throwing errors, instead of moving to the next number.